# How to assign Caps Lock (first lang) and Shift+Caps Lock (second lang) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, input-language, shortcut-keys

I want to change language layout via <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> for the first layout and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> for the second layout. How can I do this?

For example, I have two input sources in *Settings → Region & Language → Input Sources*: English(US) and Russian

[image: [image] Input Sources]

In *gnome-tweaks → Keyboard & Mouse → Additional Layout Options → Switching to another layout*: I checked option “**Caps Lock to first layout; Shift+Caps Lock to last layout**”

[image: [image] Additional Layout Options]

And then I checked in *Settings → Region & Language → Options*: it shows me that “*Alternative switch to next source*” equal “*Caps Lock to first layout; Shift+Caps Lock to last layout*” but it didn’t work

[image: [image] Input Sources Options]

I tried reassign typing shortcuts in *Settings → Devices → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts* but nothing happens when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Caps Lock</kbd>. At the same time I can assign other keys, for instance <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

[image: [image] Keyboard Shortcuts]

I also checked the *dconf-editor* options in `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/` and it seems that all options are included.

[image: [image] dconf input-sources]

Comment: I have the same problem - just wanted to use CapsLock to toggle the layout (as I always did before up to 17.10)

Comment: Hey, see [my question](/questions/1123163/modeless-stateless-layout-language-switching-with-caps-lock-again-18-04-lts-bi) about exactly the same, it has a working answer!